# Construction of stochastic processes from their discrete or continuous counterparts.

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have learnt about Levy's construction of brownian motion (the Wiener process), and its construction from the random walk.

1) I was wondering what other famous (or useful) examples are there of other continuous time stochastic processes constructed from discrete ones.

2) I also wanted to know if there are any discrete time stochastic processes constructed from discrete versions. i.e  the reverse of 1)

3) Why is brownian motion the first continuous time process people are taught. (is it the most fundamental or useful or simplest?)

Thanks

Comment: Poisson process is constructed from a random walk like process. Most textbooks on the subject contain a prelude on the history of Brownian motion. It is the process to describe the movement of certain particles. So I guess it is natural to start with something that occurs in nature in such an elementary fashion. Also, the mathematical definition of BM contains "demands" that are very natural to impose on a stochastic process (continuity, independence of increments etc).

Comment: Yes, all true. I guess Im really interested in 2) I Haven't heard of, or seen any examples of this